# Customizing UWP ListViewItem by ViewModel

Tags: windows, mvvm, uwp, win-universal-app, mvvmcross

Asking for help. 
Is there any opportunity to change ContentBorder:BorderBrush of Listviewitem by the ViewModel {Binding}?
[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhlW7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You can create an `ItemContainerStyleSelector`, where you can apply custom style based on the current item in the list.

```
public class CustomItemContainerStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public Style MyStyle1 { get; set; }
    public Style MyStyle2 { get; set; }

    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var obj = (MyObject)item;
        if (/* Some kind of condition based on the bound object */)
        {
            return MyStyle1;
        }
        else
        {
            return MyStyle2;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this style selector like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
        <local:CustomItemContainerStyleSelector>
            <local:CustomItemContainerStyleSelector.MyStyle1>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                </Style>
            </local:CustomItemContainerStyleSelector.MyStyle1>
            <local:CustomItemContainerStyleSelector.MyStyle2>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                </Style>
            </local:CustomItemContainerStyleSelector.MyStyle2>
        </local:CustomItemContainerStyleSelector>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Well, when u activate SelectionMode = Multiple, whole ListviewItem moving right to show checkboxes. I need to stick this border to the left, so the check box will appear on the right side of this border like this http://joxi.ru/v294aELS3RaaMm